# Which browser does support proxies?

Tags: browser, proxy

I'm runing ICS 4.1.1 on a Nexus. I'd like to set up a web proxy at home so I can filter pages before reading them on my Nexus when connecting over 3G (not Wi-Fi).

I looked around the settings of the two browsers that come with ICS 4.1.1...

[image]

... but I couldn't find anything related to proxies. Does it mean that those browsers don't support proxying? Is there a work-around?

Comment: Is your device rooted?

Comment: Do [search Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=Proxy). You can try Firefox with its FoxyProxy add-on.

Comment: No, it's not rooted. Thanks for the link. I'm surprised not even Chrome can use a proxy.

Comment: Proxy is at the OS level. Check your device settings. You might find something here in the [tag:proxy] tag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As pointed out by Al's comment above, it's not a question of *which browser does support it*, but rather of *how to enable it*. And as Sachin's comment suggests, available solutions depend on whether your device is rooted (more and better possibilities) or not.

### non-rooted devices

As long as it's for the browser only, there are multiple easy solutions. So does e.g. [HTTP Proxy Settings](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.credil.proxysettings) give you access to the hidden HTTP Proxy settings the Android system itself has available. For more than browsers, [ASProxy](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.Alsu.ASProxy) might be a choice -- but it's not for free. It even provides a by-pass for e.g. local networks -- so you can decide which addresses are routed via proxy, and which can be accessed directly.

### rooted devices

First-choice obviously is [ProxyDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.proxydroid): highly rated, it offers a hell of features:

1. Support HTTP / HTTPS / SOCKS4 / SOCKS5 proxy
2. Support basic / NTLM / NTLMv2 authentication methods
3. Individual proxy for only one or several apps
4. Multiple profiles support
5. Bind configuration to WIFI's SSID / Mobile Network (2G / 3G)
6. Widgets for quickly switching on/off proxy
7. Low battery and memory consumption (written in C and compiled as native binary)
8. Bypass custom IP address
9. DNS proxy for guys behind the firewall that disallows to resolve external addresses
10. PAC file support (only basic support, thanks to Rhino)

And, another big Plus: This app is *Open Source* and free!

Comment: Thanks Izzy, but on my non-rooted Galaxy Nexus 4.2.1, "HTTP Proxy Settings" is just ignored, and the browsers (Chrome and Dolphin) just hit the web directly instead of going through the local proxy I have.

Comment: What about the proxy settings provided by 4.x, when you long-press the WiFi AP in *Settings->WiFi & Wireless*? No effect either?

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I mostly use 3G to access the web, so need a solution that will work with 3G instead. Looks like I'll have to go ahead and root my phone.

Answer (score 11):

I have a Galaxy S4 and use ConnectBot to connect to my SSH server and setup a port forward via the client to port 8080. Then setup Firefox to use the SOCKS proxy by just going to About:Config and entering the following:

```
network.proxy.socks: 127.0.0.1
network.proxy.socks_port: 8080 (or whatever port you chose to forward in ConnectBot)
network.proxy.socks_remote_dns: true
network.proxy.type: 1 (this tells Firefox to use your manual proxy settings)
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

[Opera Mobile Classic](https://ftp.opera.com/pub/opera/android/classic/) also supports proxy. Note that this browser is discontinued.

Type opera:config in address bar, then scroll down to "Proxy" preference.